# multidimensional array of Directory.GetLogicalDrives()

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, directory

I have this code:

```
string[,] folders;
folders = new string[,] { Directory.GetLogicalDrives() , Directory.GetLogicalDrives() };
```

Error: `A nested array initializer is expected`

How can i fix it? i tryed everything...

**Notice:** I cannot combine the two lines of code from above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want array of arrays, not multidimensional array:

```
var folders = new string[][] { 
    Directory.GetLogicalDrives() , Directory.GetLogicalDrives() };
```

The reason is size of results of the GetLogicalDrives calls does not have to match and only known at moment of execution of each call.

Comment: Thanks! it solved it :) can you please explain to me the diffrence between a 2 dimensional array and this jagged one?

Comment: Basically if both dimensions are known and fixed you can use miltidimensional array, otherwise - jagged. I.e. tic-tac-toe field is normally represented 2 dim array as it is always 3x3, same for math computations like 10x10 matrix. In most other cases you have one dimension known and other variable - like in your case: 2 elements which are arrays of unknown length. Note that List<string> or Dictionary<...> are mused significantly more often than fixed size arrays...